# 'ManyToManyDescriptor' object has no attribute 'add' in Django with PostgreSQL

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am trying to store some data in my database, where 2 different model refer each other with 'Many-to-Many' fields.

my `models.py`:

```
class CorrectAns(models.Model):
    ansId = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    responseText1 = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    isDeleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    questionRef = models.ManyToManyField('Questions')

class Questions(models.Model):
    questionId = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    groupId = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    questionTitle = models.TextField()
    correctAnsRef = models.ManyToManyField(CorrectAns, related_name="questionReletedResponses")
```

my `views.py`:

```
for i in QuestionsList:
        questionObj = Questions(
            questionId = i['Id'],
            groupId = i['GroupId'],
            questionTitle = i['QuestionTitle'],
        )
        questionObj.save()
        for j in i['Responses']:
                correctAnsObj = CorrectAns.objects.create(
                    ansId = j['Id'],
                    responseText1 = myResponseText1,
                    isDeleted = j['IsDeleted'],
                )
                correctAnsObj.questionRef.add(questionObj)
                correctAnsObj.save()
                Questions.correctAnsRef.add(correctAnsObj)
    return
```

now it shows error with line:

```
Questions.correctAnsRef.add(correctAnsObj)
```

Like:

```
'ManyToManyDescriptor' object has no attribute 'add'
```

Please suggest how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add it to the `questionObj`, so a `Questions` *object*, not the `Questions` class:

```
questionObj.correctAnsRef.add(correctAnsObj)
```

---

> **Note**: normally a Django model is given a *singular* name, so `Question` instead of <s>`Questions`</s>.